# Rest api with same route of different entity type and using put and post method

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, methods

```
<routes>
    <route_collection>
        <route>/cart/addtocart/:device_id/:product_id/:qty</route>
        <action_type>collection</action_type>
     </route_collection>
     <route_entity>
       <route>/cart/addtocart/:device_id/:product_id/:qty</route>
        <action_type>entity</action_type>
     </route_entity>
</routes>
```

**Can we not use same route for rest API call ?** `<route_collection>` with action type collection for **POST method** and `<route_entity>` with action type entity for **PUT method?**

When I tried the above I am getting the below error.

> {"messages":{"error":[{"code":405,"message":"Resource method not
>   implemented yet."}]}}

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done following way:

Step 1: creating api2.xml in app\code\local\YourPackageName\Restapi\etc as shown beelow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
 <api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <restapi translate="title" module="restapi">
            <title>Restapi</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </restapi>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
       <addtocart translate="title" module="restapi">
            <group>restapi</group>
            <model>restapi/api2_addtocart</model>
            <title>Add to Cart</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <guest>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                </guest>
            </privileges>
            <attributes translate="data" module="restapi">
                <data>Data</data>
                <productid>Product Id</productid>
                <itemid>Item Id</itemid>
                <productname>Product Name</productname>
                <qty>Qty</qty>
                <price>Price</price>
                <options>Options</options>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                 <route_collection>
                    <route>/addToCart</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
                <route_entity>
                    <route>/addToCart/:device_id/:product_id/:qty</route>
                    <action_type>entity</action_type>
                </route_entity>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </addtocart>
    </resources>
</api2>
```

Step2: Creating model in app\code\local\YourPackageName\Restapi\Model\Api2\Addtocart.php as shown bellow :

```
class YourPackageName_Restapi_Model_Api2_Addtocart extends     Mage_Api2_Model_Resource
{
}
```

Step3: Finally extending the model **addtocart** for Guest user in app\code\local\Bluehorse\Restapi\Model\Api2\Addtocart\Rest\Guest\V1.php as shown bellow :

```
class YourPackageName_Restapi_Model_Api2_Addtocart_Rest_Guest_V1 extends YourPackageName_Restapi_Model_Api2_Addtocart
{
 protected function _create(array $data){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($data);
  exit;

  }

 protected function _update(array $data){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($data);
  exit;

  }
}
```

** POST url:/api/rest/addToCart
** PUT  url: /api/rest/addToCart/[device_id]/[product_id]/[qty]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried this , and for post it is working,When i give Put method it is showing the error

Comment: is  _update method is your model?

Comment: Sorry .I did not get that ?

Comment: did you  write  _update  method  in your model?

Comment: yes  public function _update($data)
    {
  $response = 'check';
         echo json_encode($response); die;
 }

Comment: in api2.xml , did you give privileges to user as : <update>1</update>?

Comment: yes i have given that

Comment: for POST i am able to do this.When i call PUT by using only <route_entity>
       <route>/cart/addtocart/:device_id/:product_id/:qty</route>
        <action_type>entity</action_type>
     </route_entity> without  <route_collection>...</route_collection> is also working .When I give both only POST is woking

Comment: I have edited the answer. May this fulfill your requirement.

Comment: you are using different url for both call which is not my req

Comment: You can use same base url but parameter should be different @Melvin

Comment: IS there no way that i can pass same base url and same parameters ?

Comment: As per as my knowledge it is not provided by magento

Comment: Hi thanks for the info.Anyways I will appreciate your answer.Thanks